# Post Excerpt field only showing for default administrator

Tags: metabox, excerpt

I am using the following code to add excerpts to certain post types within Wordpress and for some rather odd reason, the excerpt fields only appear for the default administrator account, i.e. `admin`

```
function connect_addexcerpt() {
    add_meta_box('postexcerpt', __('Excerpt'), 'post_excerpt_meta_box', 'page', 'normal', 'core');
    add_meta_box('postexcerpt', __('Excerpt'), 'post_excerpt_meta_box', 'clinic_location', 'normal', 'core');
    add_meta_box('postexcerpt', __('Excerpt'), 'post_excerpt_meta_box', 'clinic_group', 'normal', 'core');
    add_meta_box('postexcerpt', __('Excerpt'), 'post_excerpt_meta_box', 'career', 'normal', 'core');
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'connect_addexcerpt' );
```

<del>When creating a new user, the field is simply hidden?</del>

Edit: Sorry what I meant to say, was when logging in with a new account, the field is hidden.

Does anyone have any idea's what could be causing this?

Comment: I assume you are using Custom Post Types? If so, are you using the `supports` option and including `excerpt` when you register the post types?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, been uber busy. I've tried both setting it via the supports and using my method above. They appear fine for the default admin user, but for some reason not for other users (who are also administrators.)

Answer (score 1):

To correctly show the `Excerpt` meta box for `Custom Post` types you should use the `supports` property `register_post_type`. Supported values are as follows, and I suggest referring to the [`register_post_type` Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) for more details -

- 'title'
- 'editor' (content)
- 'author'
- 'thumbnail' (featured image, current theme must also support post-thumbnails)
- 'excerpt'
- 'trackbacks'
- 'custom-fields'
- 'comments' (also will see comment count balloon on edit screen)
- 'revisions' (will store revisions)
- 'page-attributes' (menu order, hierarchical must be true to show Parent option)
- 'post-formats' add post formats, see Post Formats

The purpose of `add_meta_box` is primarily to `"allow plugin developers to add meta boxes to the administrative interface"`. So really you should only use it to add your own custom meta boxes, and there is no need to use it to add built in meta boxes.

As a side note, the docs for `add_meta_box` also note the following -

> This function should be called from the 'add_meta_boxes' action.

## Update

Also, please check that the other users have selected to show the Excerpt box, as I believe it is hidden by default. To do this click `Screen Options` and then ensure that `Excerpt` is ticked.

[image]

Comment: Hi there, sorry about the delay. - The `register_post_type` method is also being called with `excerpt` added to the list of supported fields. Not sure what's going on :(#

Comment: Could it be as simple as the user needing to choose to show the excerpt? They can click `Screen Option` at the top of the page and tick/untick what they wish to show/hide.